# Changing the font of CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, fonts

I want to change the font in my CollapsingToolbar using fontFamily. It doesn't seem to work. My layout looks like this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="300dp"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:transitionGroup="false">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       android:id="@+id/collapsing"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTitle"
       app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
       app:expandedTitleGravity="center|bottom"
       app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
       app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTitle"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageGOD"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:transitionName="profile"
           android:visibility="visible"
           app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

       </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And I set up a fontFamily in the AppTheme. But in the toolbar, the font doesn't change. If I remove the CollapsingToolbar part then it works fine. I tried adding  `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance`. My style looks like this.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Collapsed" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/adalinescriptregular</item>
</style>
```

The font stays the same but changing the color here is working.
So I don't know what would be the solution for this. Maybe adding a **TextView** to the toolbar but it is not that easy since it is a collapsing toolbar.